# A graph with $n$ vertices has distinct degrees except for one degree, say $x$ which occurs twice. Find $x$ and prove it.

Tags: graph-theory

I find out that when $n$ is an odd number, then $x$ equals to $\frac{n-1}{2}$. When $n$ is an even number, then $x$ has two possible values, one is $\frac{n}{2}$ and another is $\frac{n}{2} -1$.
But I face difficulty in proving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: there must be a vertex adjacent to no others (degree $0$) or a vertex adjacent to all others (degree $n-1$), but not both.

If you remove this vertex, the remaining graph also has all degrees different except for one which occurs twice (unless there is only one vertex left). Also, if the removed vertex was adjacent to no others, the remaining graph has a vertex adjacent to all others, and vice versa. This should enable you to proceed by induction.

Comment: Thanks！You remind me of induction.